# ReferenceError: client is not defined Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord

I cannot figure out why its saying this error here, its telling me that client isnt defined when it is defined right here though im also unsure of anything else that im missing because all of my code so far has been from the offical documentation of discord.js
(The guild and client id's have been removed for privacy reasons)

Code:

```
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
const { token } = require('./config.json');
const fs = require('fs');

const commands = [];
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

// Place your client and guild ids here
const clientId = '';
const guildId = '';

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
}

const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken(token);

(async () => {
    try {
        console.log('Started refreshing application (/) commands.');

        await rest.put(
            Routes.applicationCommands(clientId),
            Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId),
            { body: commands },
        );

        console.log('Successfully reloaded application (/) commands.');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
})();


for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log(`${client.user.tag}`)
});

const eventFiles = fs.readdirSync('./events').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of eventFiles) {
    const event = require(`./events/${file}`);
    if (event.once) {
        client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    } else {
        client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    }
}

client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

    const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

    if (!command) return;

    try {
        await command.execute(interaction);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return interaction.reply({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
    }
});


client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

    const { commandName } = interaction;

    if (commandName === 'ping') {
        await interaction.reply('Pong!');
    } else if (commandName === 'server') {
        await interaction.reply(`Server name: ${interaction.guild.name}\nTotal members: ${interaction.guild.memberCount}`);
    } else if (commandName === 'user') {
        await interaction.reply(`Your tag: ${interaction.user.tag}\nYour id: ${interaction.user.id}`);
    }
});

client.on('interactionCreate', interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;
    console.log(interaction);
});
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

    if (interaction.commandName === 'ping') {
        await interaction.reply('Pong!');
    }
});

client.login(token);
```

Comment: You say `client` is defined, but you seem to start using it without actually declaring it. Can you point to the specific line in the code you provided that you would expect to define the `client` variable?

Comment: C:\Users\Shadow\IdeaProjects\wolf-howl\index.js:39
    client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
    ^

ReferenceError: client is not defined  this is the error that i get but how would i define it then?

Comment: Can you share where in the documentation this is purported to work without explicitly defining `client`? Even in [the documentation I am looking at currently](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome), it’s showing requiring the `Client` class from the main `discord.js` package, then declaring an instance of it like `const client = new Client(/** options here **/)`. It seems as though you may have missed that detail - I’d encourage you to re-visit the documentation.

Comment: I figured that out, but now im seeing another error here though
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'set')

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate a `Discord.Client` in order to get access to discord.js apis.

```
const {Client, Intents} = require('discord.js')
const client = new Client({intents: [/* Your intents here */]})

client.login(/* your token */)
client.on('ready', function () {
    /* client is ready */
}
```

Since discord.js v12, intents were introduced, so you will also need to use them.

More about intents: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#error-disallowed-intents

Comment: Already figured that out that i didnt have that for an unknown reason but now im facing a diffrent problem that its telling me this error right here instead, its within the same command but its still not letting me run the code here `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'set')`

Comment: You should update your post.